# Python filter and saving

Tags: python, linux

in the server contain a large log file. i want to achieve recently 5 days log data.
here is part of log file

```
    Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
    Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
    Sat Jun  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451 bytes, 1.39Kbyte/sec
    Sat Jun  2 03:32:22 2012 [pid 12677] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
    Sat Jun  2 03:32:23 2012 [pid 12676] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon password "xxxxxbot@google.com"
```

I using the code, but it has some Syntax error in open(filename). command is python ex.py vsftp.log  Can someone help me solve it. and create a new log file to save output line.  Thanks

```
from sys import argv 
import time
script, filename = argv
with open(filename) as f:
    lines= [line for line in f]
def OnlyRecent(line):
    return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")   <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5))
print "\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines))
```

but when i using code , it can work? why
      from sys import argv

```
  script, filename = argv

  txt = open(filename)

  print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
  print txt.read()
```

when i create ex.py file

```
  f =open('/opt/CLiMB/Storage1/log/vsftp.log','r')
  print f.readline
```

type python ex.py

It shows built-in method readline of file object at 0x...
How to solve it. Thanks

Comment: with open(filename) as f:
            ^

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Maybe you are passing an incorrect filename, or you don't have the rights to read that file. We can't know without seeing the error.
If you're using relative paths, then make sure the relative path is correct with respect to the current working directory.

Comment: it shows SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i have rights to read this file

Answer (score 1):

the format date string is wrong, it should be

```
"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
```

you can `man strftime` from the shell to see what to put (amongst other sources!)

Comment: it also has SyntaxError in  open(filename) as f

Answer (score 1):

You might check that h,m and s are capital in strptime, like "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y":

```
return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")   <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5))
```

As another note, you might surround the return with a try/except statement in case the date time is wrong, or there is a multi-line statement in the log file that would bugger it up.

```
def OnlyRecent(line):
    try:
       return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")   <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5))
    except:
       return False
```

For Python 2.4.3, I don't think the file reading syntax works that you're using.  Try something like:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

More on the docs for 2.4.3 here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/tut/node9.html#SECTION009200000000000000000

Comment: it also has SyntaxError in open(filename) as f

Comment: Are you using python 2.5 by any chance? If not, what version of python are you using?

Comment: If you are on python 2.5, try an `import __future__` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685097/syntax-error-when-using-with-open-in-python-python-newbie

Comment: i try to just open file delete the import time and OnlyRecent() function

Comment: Try using f.readlines() to get the contents of the file - the `with open(filename) as f` might not work in python 2.4

Comment: Thanks, it also has same question in f= open, i can using open（filename) as f, if i just read and print file

Comment: Add this to the top of your file `from __future__ import with_statement`